# While loop through a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I am entering `"901000"` as an argument to the following method, and I expect it to remove the last three zeros and return `"901"`.

```
def zeros(x)
    str = x.to_s
    i = str.length-1
    while str[i] == "0"
        str = str.delete(str[i])
        i = i-1
    end
    return str
end
```

But it returns `"91"` instead. I cannot understand why my code does not work. Can someone help please?

Comment: I assume you want to remove *all* trailing zeroes, not necessarily three. If so you should clarify that with an edit.

Comment: Use `str.chop` or `str.chop!` instead of `str.delete(str[i])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, `str` is `"901000"`, `i = str.length-1` is `5`, and `str[i]` is `"0"`. Hence,

```
str = str.delete(str[i])
```

is equivalent to

```
str = "901000".delete("0")
```

That gives you `"91"`.

Then, by `i = i-1`, `i` becomes `4`, and `str[i]` (which is equivalent to `"91"[4]`) becomes `nil`, and `str[i] == 0` (which is equivalent to `nil == 0`) becomes `false`. So the loop ends, returning the value `str`, which is `"91"`.

---

To do what you want, some simple ways are:

```
"901000".sub(/0+\z/, "") # => "901"
"901000"[/.*?(?=0+\z)/] # => "901"
```

Comment: I don't like it as well, but here's a way that doesn't use a regex: `str.reverse.to_i.to_s.reverse`.

Comment: Also `str.chomp!("0") while str[-1] == '0'`.

Comment: @mudasobwa You may as well use `chop!` since your while loop already checks that `"0"` is the last character.